# Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{1} (1+x^{2})^{-1.5} dx$

Tags: integration

How can we evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1} (1+x^{2})^{-1.5} dx$$

Comment: See http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html

Comment: Let $x=\tan\theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^{2})^{\frac 32}} dx$$
we now let $x= \tan \theta$, therefore $dx = \sec^2 \theta \,d\theta$. We also change our limits of integration to reflect the substitution
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{\sec^2 \theta \,d\theta}{(1+\tan^{2}\theta)^{\frac 32}}$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{\sec^2 \theta \,d\theta}{(\sec^2 \theta)^{\frac 32}}$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{\sec^2 \theta \,d\theta}{\sec^3 \theta}$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{d\theta}{\sec \theta}$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4} \cos \theta \, d\theta$$
I think you can get it from here (let me know if you still need help though!)

Answer (score 3):

Pull $x^2$ out of the bracket.

$$\int {1\over ({1+x^2})^{3/2}}dx=\int {{x^{-3}}\over ({1+x^{-2}})^{3/2}}dx$$

Substitute $t=x^{-2}$

$$I=({1+x^{-2}})^{-1/2}$$ And put the limits

Comment: Slick!  + 1 ... -Mark

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\left(1+x^2\right)^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2^{-1/2}+\int_0^1x^2\left(1+x^2\right)^{-3/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=2^{-1/2}+\int_0^1\left(\left(1+x^2\right)^{-1/2}-\left(1+x^2\right)^{-3/2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
\int_0^1\left(1+x^2\right)^{-3/2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2^{-1/2}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: integrate by parts
$(2)$: $x^2=\left(1+x^2\right)-1$
$(3)$: cancel left side of $(1)$ with $(2)$